# Make neovim background the same colour as the terminal background

Tags: neovim, terminal, colorscheme, macos

In addition to what was asked above, is there also a way for (neo)vim background colour to change when the terminal background colour is changed?

It's running in OSX in the default terminal app.

Comment: are you running neovim inside a terminal like gnome-terminal/konsole/iterm2 ?

Comment: @YonsySolis It's running on the default terminal app in OSX.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to use `colorscheme=default`.  This assumes changing the other colors is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Seiya](https://github.com/miyakogi/seiya.vim) plugin,  this one works for me. Check that for NeoVim [one option is needed](https://github.com/miyakogi/seiya.vim#change-highlight-groups-to-clear) and in any case, install first and check with the command `SeiyaEnable` first.